# My dataset as "?" values. How can I find all the missing values with R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to find all the missing values in my data set. I'm using R and I tried the is.na function and it didn't work. Missing entries in my dataset have a "?"

Comment: Try `df=="?"`..

Comment: Hi sorry thanks for that. What will df=="?" do?

Comment: Okay! That worked for the first row, do you know how I can get it to run for all rows?

Comment: If you have used `read.table` to import your data.frame, then you can use set `na.strings = "?"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df=="?"] <- NA
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Tried that and nothing executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey if you run this line, your df should now have NA instead of "?". Then you can use na.omit(df) to remove the rows that contain NAs or use replace_na to replace the NAs with anything else you want by column.

df %>%
tidyr::replace_na(list(column_name=0))

for example will replace NA with 0 in the column called "column_name"